# this error is faced me in writing in prolog language --- (Syntax error: Operator expected ) in the if statement

Tags: prolog

```
questions2() :-
   repeat, 
   (
      tab(40),writeln(' Whenerver you want to end the conversation , please type "bye" ! '),
      tab(10),writeln('---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'),nl,
      tab(10),writeln('Based on Advanture selection '),
      tab(10),writeln('Are you afraid from high places ? '),nl,
      read(h),
      (
          (     
            (h =='bye') 
          ->
            end()
          ),          
          not(h == 'yes'),
          not(h == 'no'),   
          not(h =='bye')
      ->
          tab(10),writeln(" you have entered an invalid input ! , please try again."),
          fail
      ),
      !
   ),
   !.
    
(   
   (
      h =='yes'
   >-
      safari()
   )
;
   (
      h =='no'
   >- 
      fogWalkWay()
   )
).
```

Comment: Replace `>-` by `->`

Comment: And, replace `questions2()` by `questions2`.

Comment: I have another error can i share it with you

Comment: Moreover the `( (h =='yes'>- safari())  ; (h =='no'>- fogWalkWay())).` part is separate from the rest of the predicate definition (the line above ends with a dot). Is this your query or do you want this as part of question2?

Comment: do you mean i should end the line with a comma, not a dot

Comment: If you want it as additional conditions for question2, then it needs to be a comma, yes.

Comment: I would also recommend going through a Prolog tutorial, e.g. [this one](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog). You seem to struggle with some basic notions (variables vs. constants, declarative vs. imperative programs) and it could clear up some questions.

Comment: One more:  `(  (h =='bye') ->  end() ), ` this will always fail.

Comment: [Adventure in Prolog](https://www.amzi.com/AdventureInProlog/advtop.php) might be another tutorial that's a bit closer to what you want to do.